# Problems with chisq_test in R coin package

Tags: r, chi-squared

this is my first question on stackoverflow, so hopefully I will give you all the necessary information.

I'm trying to conduct a chi-squared test based on an exact distribution, using the `chisq_test` function in the `coin` package. I'd like to compare two groups concerning one variable but I'm running in a warning message. Here's a minimum reproducible example (at least I hope it is one):

```
library(coin)

dt <- as.data.frame(alzheimer)

xtabs(~ disease + gender, data = dt)

chisq_test(disease ~ gender, data = dt, distribution = "exact")
```

I'm checking the contingency table to make sure, there are enough cases per cell. When I'm conducting the test, I get this output:

```
> chisq_test(disease ~ gender, data = dt, distribution = "exact")

    Exact Pearson Chi-Squared Test

data:  disease by gender (Female, Male)
chi-squared = 9.7121, p-value = 0.3895

Warning messages:
1: In T - expectation(object) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (T - expectation(object))^2/variance(object) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I calculated the p-value using an approximate distribution, to make sure, the warning really is a problem:

```
> chisq_test(disease ~ gender, data = dt, distribution = approximate(nresample = 1e+05))

    Approximative Pearson Chi-Squared Test

data:  disease by gender (Female, Male)
chi-squared = 9.7121, p-value = 0.00756
```

Since both p-values differ a lot, I guess there is something going wrong using the exact distribution, but I just can't figure out the problem.

Maybe someone can help me solve the problem or understand the reason for the warning.

Comment: Could you please give insight of your dataframe? The error states, that your input data differs. Could it be, that `gender` and `disease` is not of equal length? Got `NAs`? Or something similar? Also try your code with an example dataset. This way you can be sure, that your code is right and your issue is with the data.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The dataframe is some data coming with the coin package, so I considered it an exaple dataset. I used this data to get a reproducible example.
There are no `NAs` in the data and both `gender` and `disease` are of equal length.

With this additional information: Is it still necessary to try out with some other data?

Comment: a 2x3 exact test is not supported it seems `chisq_test(table(dt$disease, dt$gender), distribution = 'exact')`, and the formula method does not correctly catch the error

Comment: If you just change the input to `chisq_test(table(dt$gender, dt$disease), distribution = 'exact')` you get the same output I posted. So the number of rows in the table has to be two. In `?chisq_test` it reads `the distribution can be ... computed exactly for univariate two-sample problems by setting distribution to ... "exact"`, so there shouldn't be a limit for the number of columns (as long it's a 2xk table or problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to Torsten Hothorn, one of the authors of the package. He told me that the exact distribution for the chi-squared test only works in the case of 2x2 problems. So the warning or the fact that you don't get an error message is a bug in the current version 1.3-1 of the `coin` package. In the R-forge version of the package this bug is already fixed.